# Allow connections to postgres container from other containers, but no outside machines

Tags: ubuntu, docker, postgresql

Using postgres 14 or 15 as a docker container, with a port in the host bind to the 5432 port of the container, with the following configuration in the pg_hba.conf file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

# host all all all scram-sha-256

host all test,prod samenet scram-sha-256
host all read_bi all scram-sha-256
```

having the postgres container in the same docker network with other two containers, all three of them with their own static ip

I understand that with such configuration i accomplish the following: i put a comment in this line to disable remote connections in general

**#host all all all scram-sha-256**

i allow the test and prod users to make connections from within the same server, the host holding the containers, to make connections to postgres, such users are used by other containers that use postgres to host its databases those users wouldnt be able to connect from outside the server, by example, i couldnt connect using such users with psql from a remote machine

**host all test,prod samenet scram-sha-256**

i allow the read_bi user to connect from a remote server to any database, such user only has select permissions over the tables of a particular database

**host all read_bi all scram-sha-256**

in short, with this configuration, only read_bi would be able to connect from an outside machine, test and prod would be able to connect from within their respective containers in the host server but not from a remote machine and no other user would be able to connect from a remote machine, am i correct?

i came up with the previous configuration in the pg_hba, but im not an expert and would like an expert opinion